# Error with go_router while doing a phone auth with Firebase on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, captcha

I'm making a Flutter app with go_router as my router. Everything works fine, but when I want to authenticate myself with Firebase, the code is sent, but then I'm redirected to an unknown route "link".
However, I never wrote this route, and it blocks me since I got an error screen from go_router :

`GoException: no routes for location: /link?deep_link_id=https://appid.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/callback?authType=verifyApp&recaptchaToken=somecaptchadata&eventId=zwmpjkyfjc`

May someone here could know why I got this error only on iOS, and how can I handle this case for the recaptcha ?
I'm using go_router `12.0.1` and firebase_auth `4.12.0`.

Thank you very much.

I tried pretty much everything I saw in every docs Firebase gave us. This issue seems not to be reported by someone else. I don't really understand why the captcha verification is a success, but redirect me to a route.

Comment: As I think, this redirect to recaptcha will only shown in debug mode,
when the user downloads the app from play store, this direct will not shown anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am encountering the same issue. This seems to happen when you tell Flutter to handle deeplinks by setting `FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled` to `YES` in your Info.plist file. See https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-universal-links for details.

Comment: That was, indeed, the solution. Thank you very much! Now everything works fine.

Comment: @Elias What was the solution ? This answers seem to be indicating a cause, not a solution

Comment: @Ced You should not le Flutter handle natively deeplinks, but letting GoRouter. To do so, deactivate FlutterDeepLinkingEnabled, and use GoRouter deeplinks handler instead.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to ignore this path in the go router onException.